# Find and replace value with a vlookup on other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple cells containing text data and would like to replace some data with data from another sheet.

**Example**

*Sheet 1*

> A1= "aa*a"
>
> B1= "b]bb"
>
> C1= "cae*"

*Sheet 2*

> A1="q" B1="Quote"
>
> A2="e" B2="Example"

**Result**

`A1` stays the same, `B1` stays the same and `C1` changes to `caExample*`

I guess I need an VBA code for a find and replace with an `VLookUp`.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Try [substitute](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/substitute-function-HP010062578.aspx)

Comment: Sheet1 will ways have 3 cells and you want to change only C1? What if C1 has "caqcae*". Do you want the output as "caQuotecaExample*"

Comment: Yes, all columns will have data on one row (1:1) and all these data can be changes with the value's on sheet 2. In your example "caqcae*" will indeed output as "caQuotecaExample*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub PolyChange()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, v1 As String
    Dim N1 As Long, N2 As Long, v2 As String, v3 As String
    N1 = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    N2 = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 1 To N1
        v1 = s1.Cells(I, "A")
        For J = 1 To N2
            v2 = s2.Cells(J, "A")
            v3 = s2.Cells(J, "B")
            v1 = Replace(v1, v2, v3)
        Next J
        s1.Cells(I, "A").Value = v1
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this works, but only for cell A1 in sheet1. I would need to format all rows 1:1.

Comment: @GeLi   Your question indicated  **A1 A2 A3** that is a **column** ...........is this not what you want??

Comment: You are right, sorry for the mistake. I've edited the code...!

Comment: Your code works great for column changes but could you guide me for my edited code (row changes)?